# Spring docs - Open API 3 - How to set default values to body?

Tags: spring, springdoc, springdoc-openui

I am using **Spring Boot + Spring Data Mongo + Spring REST + Spring HATEOAS** to implement REST endpoints.

Since we're passing more than 5 Query Parameters (proprietary setting of an Org, supposed to be not passed), so I though to create a EmployeeDto Class and pass that class at Controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/employees", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public ResponseEntity<PagedModel<EmployeeModel>> findEmployees(
        EmployeeDto dto,
        @Parameter(hidden=true) String sort,
        @Parameter(hidden=true) String order,
        @Parameter(hidden=true) Pageable pageRequest) {

    // Add needed logic 
    ......
    ......
    ......
    PagedModel<EmployeeModel> model = employeePagedAssembler.toModel(response, employeeAssembler);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(model, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Swagger UI it shows like -

```
{
  "firstName": "string",
  "lastName": "string",
  "age": 0,
  "languageCd": "string",
  "isActive": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "regionCd": "string"
}
```

**CURL Command:**

> curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/employee-data/employees/geographies?firstName=string&lastName=string&age=0&languageCd=string&isActive=string&email=string&regionCd=string&page=0&size=25&sort=firstName&order=ASC" -H "accept: application/json"

EmployeeDto.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Schema
public class EmployeeDto {
    @Schema(description = AppConstants.FIRSTNAME, defaultValue="")
    private String firstName; 

    @Schema(description = AppConstants.LASTNAME, defaultValue="")
    private String lastName; 

    @Schema(description = AppConstants.AGE, defaultValue="")
    private Integer age; 

    @Schema(description = AppConstants.LANG_CD_DESC, defaultValue="0")
    private String languageCd;

    @Schema(description = AppConstants.ISACTIVE, defaultValue="")
    private String isActive; 

    @Schema(description = AppConstants.EMAIL, defaultValue="")
    private String email; 

    @Schema(description = AppConstants.REGION_CD_DESC, defaultValue="")
    private String regionCd;
}
```

I am looking for -

1) How to set the default value for each field instead of "string" which seem coming default?

2) How to simply allow to see actual query parameters in OAS3 UI ? Currency, it look like body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue myself. `example - Provides an example of the schema.  When associated with a specific media type, the example string shall be parsed by the consumer to be treated as an object or an array.`

Code -

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Schema
public class EmployeeDto {
    @Schema(description = AppConstants.FIRSTNAME, type = "string", example = " ")
    private String firstName; 

    @Schema(description = AppConstants.LASTNAME, type = "string", example = " ")
    private String lastName; 

    @Schema(description = AppConstants.AGE, type = "string", example = "null")
    private Integer age; 

    @Schema(description = AppConstants.LANG_CD_DESC, type = "string", example = " ")
    private String languageCd;

    @Schema(description = AppConstants.ISACTIVE, type = "string", example = " ")
    private String isActive; 

    @Schema(description = AppConstants.EMAIL, type = "string", example = " ")
    private String email; 

    @Schema(description = AppConstants.REGION_CD_DESC, type = "string", example = " ")
    private String regionCd;
}
```

and at the controller simply add the below method that will reset if `"null"` value sent, if yes it will reset it to `""` and same for `Integer` to `null`.

```
public static Object getDefaulter(Object obj) {
    Arrays.stream(obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()).map(f -> {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            // set null values only if found String value as "null"
            if (Objects.equals(f.get(obj), "null")) {
                f.set(obj, "");
            }else if(Objects.equals(f.get(obj), 0)) {
                f.set(obj, null);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            //
        }
        return f;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. String with a space is ignored just like an empty one is.